# Referencing deleted function Array

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to return an entity within a `std::vector`, but the compiler is telling me that I am referencing a deleted function.

```
vector<unique_ptr<Node>> children;        //member of a class

unique_ptr<Node> Node::selectNext() {    //function for a class
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
        if (children[i]->getUI().mouseSelect())
            return children[i];           //Problem is in this return statement
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

I believe the compiler is conflicting with the smart pointer.

This is probably a relatively easy problem to fix, but I am not sure what I did wrong. The issue may be bigger than this because this class is a node class.

Comment: You need to give us the *complete* code to reproduce the issue. The compiler error is a pretty basic thing you should include as well.  We can't see your monitor.

Comment: You're trying to copy the pointer which is not possible. The fix depends on what you actually need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot share unique ptrs.

```
Node* Node::selectNext() {    //function for a class
  for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
    if (children[i]->getUI().mouseSelect())
        return children[i].get();
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually makes alot of sense when I think about about it like that.

Comment: If you are going to be passing Node pointers around, better to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, shared pointer doesn't solve "you are going to be passing it around" problems.  Well, it "solves" it like regular expressions solve HTML parsing problems.  Shared pointers means you explicitly want the lifetime of this object to be under shared management, which is *not* a simplifying assumption in 99/100 cases.  The lifetime of a node in a tree being managed by the tree is a simple model.  The lifetime being the union of all dangling pointers is an extremely complex model.

Comment: @Yakk it does solve it, if the tree stores nodes as `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`, then `selectNext` can return a `shared_ptr`. The whole point of `shared_ptr` is passing around pointers without worrying the objects will disappear unexpectedly

Comment: @RemyLebeau And now you have a tree whose nodes lifetime is usually going to require solving a halt-complete problem.  Or, you could keep lifetimes simple, and have the tree own its own nodes.  There are situations where you want to use shared pointer; knee-jerk "I pass a pointer to it so it should be shared" leads to horrible spaghetti lifetime issues.  The point of shared pointer is to make "shared lifetime management" easier when you need it; the curse is that people grab it when *they don't need shared lifetime management* and make their code insanely more complex.